# Function inside JSX, is not returning the elements: ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add extra rows on a table that is generated using results.map, but the code that I have added to generate the extra rows isn't executing. Does anyone know why this wouldn't work?

```
< tbody >
    {
        results.map(result => {
            let rowNodes = [];
            rowNodes.push(<td className="hidden">{result.itemCtrlType}</td>);
            if (this.props.gridNumber == 1) {
                rowNodes.push(<td className="in-td-item">{result.metric}</td>);
            } else {
                rowNodes.push(<td className="in-td-item hidden">{result.metric}</td>);
            }
            for (const hour in result) {
                if (hour.indexOf('t') == 0 && hour.length == 3) {
                    let now = Date.now();
                    let d = new Date(now);
                    let hours = d.getHours();
                    let time = hours.toString();
                    if (hours < 10) {
                        time = 't0' + hours;
                    }
                    else {
                        time = 't' + hours;
                    };
                    let classname = "in-td";
                    if (hour == time && this.props.dateAdjust == 0) {
                        classname += " cell-timenow";
                    }
                    if (hour == 't23') {
                        classname += " table-lastcolumn";
                    }
                    let date = [pad(d.getMonth() + 1), pad(d.getDate()), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
                    rowNodes.push(<td key={hour} className={classname} >{result[hour]}</td>)
                }
            }
            if (this.props.gridNumber == this.props.totalGrids) {
                rowNodes.push(<td className="in-td-addcolumn in-td"></td>);
            }
            return <tr key={result.metric} onClick={this.handleClick}>{rowNodes}</tr>
        })
    }
    {
        () => {
            console.log(this.props.rowsCount > results.length);
            if (this.props.rowsCount > results.length) {
                let diff = this.props.rowsCount - results.length;
                var rowNodes = [];
                for (let m = 0; m < diff; m++) {
                    rowNodes.push(<td className="hidden"></td>);
                    if (this.props.gridNumber == 1) {
                        rowNodes.push(<td className="in-td-item"></td>);
                    } else {
                        rowNodes.push(<td className="in-td-item hidden"></td>);
                    }
                    for (let n = 0; n < 24; n++) {
                        rowNodes.push(<td className="in-td"></td>);
                    }
                    if (this.props.gridNumber == this.props.totalGrids) {
                        rowNodes.push(<td className="in-td-addcolumn in-td"></td>);
                    }
                    return <tr>{rowNodes}</tr>
                }
            }
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

I have tried various combinations of wrapping it in divs or changing where it returns but nothing seems to work.

Anyone know why this isn't firing?

Comment: you are talking about: `() => {...}` this code that is not working, correct?

Comment: Yes that's the section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, that is not a good way of organising code, instead of putting the function directly inside JSX, better to define it outside of render method and then call.

**Solution:**

Issue with your code is, you defined a function inside JSX, but you are not calling it, Use **[IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)** and call that function, also `return null` when if condition fails, Like this:

```
{
    (() => {
        console.log(this.props.rowsCount > results.length);
        if (this.props.rowsCount > results.length) {
            let diff = this.props.rowsCount - results.length;
            var rowNodes = [], elements = [];
            for (let m = 0; m < diff; m++) {
                rowNodes = [];
                rowNodes.push(<td className="hidden"></td>);
                if (this.props.gridNumber == 1) {
                    rowNodes.push(<td className="in-td-item"></td>);
                } else {
                    rowNodes.push(<td className="in-td-item hidden"></td>);
                }
                for (let n = 0; n < 24; n++) {
                    rowNodes.push(<td className="in-td"></td>);
                }
                if (this.props.gridNumber == this.props.totalGrids) {
                    rowNodes.push(<td className="in-td-addcolumn in-td"></td>);
                }
                elements.push(<tr key={m}>{rowNodes}</tr>);
            }
            return elements;
        }
        return null;
    })()
}
```

**Note**:

Whenever execution find `return` statement inside `for` loop, it will immediately break the loop and return that result, so instead of using return use one more variable and put the `tr` inside that, Return the result only after `for` loop completion.

**Suggestion:**

Assign unique key to each dynamically created elements inside loop.

Check [**DOC**](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Check this answer for more details about keys: [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Comment: Wow thanks for all the helpful information. Should I also be putting keys on <td> elements as well? Or just <tr> in this case?

Comment: yea, define the keys with the td also, concept is: "keys should be uniques among its siblings" so all the td inside `tr` should have the uniques keys, you can use same keys again for all other `td's` inside another `tr` :)

Comment: check [DOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for more details.